# Jquery Tooltip inside Scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a tooltip based on this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-better-tooltip-with-jquery-awesomeness/) which uses jquery .offset() for position. [page with tooltip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12361619/Dorm2.0/DormApp.html)

When I place a tooltip inside a scrollable it is incorrectly positioned for all but the first scrollable item due to overflow (I think).

Any ideas for fixes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the tooltip uses fixed coordinates to display. So there is no easy fix. You could have the possison modified based on the amount you scroll. Say if you scroll 50px in the scrollable, you move the tooltip 50px y axis. This would require modifying the properties directly, and it might cause some weird problems.

Thats my 2 cents on how you would fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Using .position() not .offset() I could position relative to the tool tips element (the one with the title attribute) and not the body avoiding the issues.  Solved.

Comment: You can click the solution check under the vote box so I get internet points... I need to feed my family!!!!